# Get google apis in unsupported mobiles?

Tags: android, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I have an android application that requires google maps api. I figured out that in some mobiles neither support google apis or google play by default.

By googling the workaround that I found was to add

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps android:required="false"/>`

This makes that app to be installed on those mobiles but doesnot support loading the maps.

So is there a way to add google apis externally and support google maps loading for those mobiles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there a way to add google apis externally and support google maps loading for those mobiles ?

No, except perhaps by rooting the device and installing pirated software.

Note that Maps V2 does not require pre-installed mapping APIs, though it does require the Play Services Framework, which in turn requires the Play Store.

If you want mapping support without these limitations, use something independent, like OpenStreetMap and OSMDroid.

Comment: @arul: Correct. Basically, anything on this page requires the Play Services Framework: http://developer.android.com/google/index.html